# Density of $ \{rn^2\} $

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Given an irrational number $r$, let $ \{ r \times n^2 \} $ denote the fractional part of $rn^2$ where $n$ is an integer.

Is the set of $ \{ r\times n^2 \} $ dense in $[0,1]$?

More generally, for what functions $ f(n)$, is the set $ \{ r\times f(n)\}$ dense in $[0,1]$?

---

It is well known that the set of $\{r \times n\}$ is dense in $[0,1]$, but I cannot extend the standard pigeonhole principle.

Comment: According to [a result by Weyl](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WeylsCriterion.html), for any (non-constant) polynomial $P$ with integral coefficients and any irrational number $\gamma$, the sequence $\{P(n)\gamma\}$ is uniformly distributed in $[0,1]$, therefore dense.

Comment: @CaveJohnson You comment answers OP's question completely, I think---perhaps consider promoting it to an answer proper?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As already stated in the comments, [Weyl's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl%27s_inequality) gives a way for producing non-trivial bounds for exponential sums of the form $\sum_{n=1}^{N} e^{2\pi i\alpha n^2}$ for any $\alpha\not\in\mathbb{Q}$. This implies the sequence $\{\alpha n^2\pmod{1}\}$ is [equidistributed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistributed_sequence), hence dense.

As a major overkill, [Sarkozy's theorem](https://arxiv.org/abs/1107.0243) gives that in any subset of $\mathbb{N}$ with positive density there are two distinct elements whose difference is a square. It follows that the set of squares is a [Heilbronn set](https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.03049) and the same conclusion holds.